# Upload and save to database with php and jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-ajaxq

i'm a amateur programer. I'm  coding upload and insert to database function with php and jquery ajax but it not work
my form

```
<form>
<input type="file" id='iputfile1' />
</form>
```

my jquery script

```
 iputfile1 = $("#iputfile1").val();
jQuery.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"ex.php", //goi toi file ajax.php
            data:"filename"=filename+"&+"&iputfile1="
        +iputfile1,
        success:function(html){
         jQuery("#responseDiv").show();
         jQuery("#responseDiv").html(html);
        }
       });
```

my ex.php file

```
$iputfile1 = $_REQUEST['iputfile1'];
print_r($iputfile1)
```

after select file and submit my ex.php file not recivice $_file['tmp']

Comment: you can use `FormData` object in javascript, and do note that uploaded files are inside `$_FILES`, search here on SO, theres already a tons of content regarding file uploaded thru jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="file" class="file">


$(".file").on("change",function(){
   var file = new FormData();
   file.append('file',$('.file')[0].files[0]);
   $.ajax({
    url: "upload.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: file,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false, 
     beforeSend:function(){
    $(".result").text("Loading ...");
     }, 
     success:function(data){
      $(".result").html(data);
    }
});


<div class="result"></div>

in upload.php


<?php
include("database.php");
$name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "DESTINATION/".$name)){
      // insert to data base
      echo '<img src="DESTINATION/'.$name.'">';
}
?>
```